# What is the RenPrivateItem file format in the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, outlook

I was working to allow an Outlook attachment to be drag-n-dropped from the subject line of an email.  To do this I needed to handle the file as a RenPrivateItem.  Everything works alright but I was hoping somebody could define the "RenPrivateItem" format in the context of .NET, or otherwise.

I would like to know why my code works but I could not find any further information on this format via a web search.

Also, I am working with Visual Studio 2012 and Outlook 2007.

EDIT:

I am somewhat unfamiliar with the process of handling the DragDrop but I am guessing that there are only certain types of documents that are supposed to be handled by it.  I was given an example of a file that currently works (attachment .pdf contained in email body) and an example that does not (attachment .pdf contained in email subject-line).  The working example returns true on the following line and is handled:

```
ElseIf idoData.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf, False) Then
```

The example that does not work is not handled by any of the cases visible in the code block below.  My task was to figure out why it doesn't work (it is the same file, just attached to the email in a different place).  Since I do not understand what the file formats I'm receiving are, with the exception of .rtf, I am finding it difficult to know how to handle the other case:

```
Shared Sub ProcessOutlookDrop(ByVal idoData As Windows.Forms.IDataObject, ByVal
                          iIdReport As Integer, ByVal iIdFileReference As Integer)

  If idoData.GetDataPresent("RenPrivateFileAttachments") Then
     byFile = getFiledataArrayFromFileContents(idoData)
  ElseIf idoData.GetDataPresent("RenPrivateItem") Then   ' ADDED BY ME
     byFile = getFiledataArrayFromFileContents(idoData)  ' ADDED BY ME
  ElseIf idoData.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf, False) Then
     byFile = getFiledataArrayFromFileContents(idoData)
  ElseIf idoData.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text, False) Then
     byFile = getMessagedataArrayFromOutlook(idoData)
  End If
```

For the working example (.pdf attachment in the body) I am getting formats of:
Woozle, Object Descriptor, Rich Text Format, HtmlFormat, EnhancedMetafile, MetaFilePict, DeviceIndependentBitmap, System.Drawing.Bitmap, Bitmap, Embedded Object, FileGroupDescriptor, FileContents

For the broken example (.pdf attachment in the subject line) I am getting formats of:
FileGroupDescriptorW, FileGroupDescriptor, RenPrivateItem, FileContents

In addition to my initial question, why are these files handled so differently?

Answer (score 0):

The `RenPrivateItem` data format is not .NET-specific. It's an undocumented private format Outlook uses to track its own items. It's not relevant to the outside world; only `FileGroupDescriptorW`, `FileGroupDescriptor`, and `FileContents` are relevant.

That's why the word 'private' is in the name; this is what it looks like when an app wants to associate private data with a drag and drop operation. My own applications do this.